# incomplete Mathematical operation in two column using interrows() in panda

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, subtraction

Hi I am trying to subtract 2 column data of dataframe and put it into new dataframe. I am using for loop in interrows(). However loop is not completing all calculation since the size of row is smaller than columns. The column will be increasing in future hence I am using loop instead of column name.
Is there anyway or alternate way to perform this calculation.

```
    name  col1 col2     col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8
    John    0   23      0        1      4       1       5      23
1   victor  1   4       5        2      1       4       2      15
2   Alida   1   1       2        6      0       2       14      2
3   Natalie 0   1       1        4      2       3       4       4
4   Morman  3   3       1        0      5       2       0       1
```

I tried running following  code :

```
for label, row in df.iterrows():
    df2.iloc[:,[label+2]]=df.iloc[:,[label+2]].values-df.iloc[:,[label+1]].values
```

However loop does not run after col6. i am guessing it is because of number of row is less than column.
outcome:

```
       name     col1 col2   col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8
0      John     0     23    -23    1        3       -3       5       23
1     victor    1     3      1    -3       -1       3        2       15
2     Alida     1     0      1     4       -6       2       14        2
3     Natalie   0     1      0     3       -2       1        4        4
4     Morman    3     0     -2    -1        5      -3        0        1
```

is  there anyway to run loop until it run through all column ?

Comment: Can you explain what you are wanting to see as the output? Also, when you iterate with `iterrows`, label will be the row index, but you are using that as a column index with iloc. Also, `iterrows` is really slow, so if you give more explanation about what you're trying to do we might be able to find a better function for you to use. Though I'm not sure what you're trying to get, it sounds like you might want to look at using the `diff` method, and might need to transpose your dataframe beforehand.

Comment: I want to see for col7 =difference of col7 & col6. Is  there any other function that will run calculation in all value of dataframe . I tried using label in col but it does not work . @teepee

Comment: makes sense now; see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `diff` method for your data frame to subtract each column from the adjacent. For example:

```
df.set_index('name').diff(axis=1)
```

This sets your name column as the row index, and then does the subtractions for each column from the next column. As you mentioned, there will be one column less in the output, so the resultant col1 is going to be NaNs.

Comment: Hi , This can be work around. But what about If I have to subtract values from two different dataframe column where   row<column ?  Hence I want to use index to point value.

Comment: not sure what you mean where row < column? The number of rows is less than the number of columns? I don't see why that would be an issue; can you explain with an example?

Comment: when I use **for label, row in df.iterrows():** label takes value of row size of dataframe which is 5. But my current dataframe has 9 columns(this will increase in future). Due to this, loop will only run 5 times which means calculation will happen upto col6 only. & want a way loop to go through all column.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to subtract two specefic columns say col1 and col2 use this:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
data = {"name":["john","victor","alida","natalie","morman"],"col1":[0,1,2,3,4],"col2":[5,6,7,8,9],"col3":[0,1,2,3,4],"col4":[5,6,7,8,9],"col5":[0,1,2,3,4],"col6":[5,6,7,8,9],"col7":[0,1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df["new_col"] = df["col1"] - df["col2"]
print(new_df)
```

if you want for example subtract every column from the adjacent one use this:

```
cols = df.columns
for i in range(2,len(cols)-1):
    new_df["new_" + cols[i]] = df[cols[i]]-df[cols[i-1]]
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Dataframe Column will increase in future . I think it got deleted when I was posting question hence I want to use  index value instead of column name .

Comment: you don't need to loop here; there is a built-in method called `diff` that does this.